# Confirmation message from the ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

How to use a confirmation message in asp.net like yes/no message box in windows form applications. I need to continue the same method after the action taken.

Comment: use javasrcipts confirm message

Comment: You can use JavaScript `confirm()` method. However, it looks bad and it is a bad practice. A good approach is to implement HTML message form with two buttons - "yes" and "no". They should lead to a specified URL or execute JavaScript code. Everything is up to your fantasy.

Comment: You must accept one of the answer if your problem is resolved

Answer (score 1):

you can use OnClientClick to get confirmation:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnOK" runat="server" Text="Button" 
OnClick="btnOK_Click" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to 
Delete ?')" ></asp:Button>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But if i use this method, confirmation will popup when the button clicked and yes/ no actions leads to another event or method. but in my situation i want to take to return value into the same event( ex: save btn click ) and take action. Is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: protected void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (true)
            {
                Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(updatepanel1, updatepanel1.GetType(), id.ToString(), "alert('thank you');", true);
                datetime();//this function basically showing datetime in lbltime label
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
<asp:Button ID="somebutton" Text="Delete" runat="server" 
OnClientClick="return confirm("Are tou sure you want to delete ?");" 
OnClick="SomeEvent"></asp:Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

For better UI, you can use jQuery plugin with css. Have a look at this:
http://tutorialzine.com/2010/12/better-confirm-box-jquery-css3/